# Get the textbox value on same page modal in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to fetch the value of a textbox on a modal popup in `Laravel`, using `isset($_POST['freq_dates'])` as we do in `PHP` but it doesn't work, even not moving inside in `if()` also and displaying `else{}` part.

I also tried storing the value in a variable like this

```
$data = $_POST['freq_dates'];
```

but it gives this error

> Undefined index: freq_dates

Here is a more complete overview of my code

```html
<!-- Calling the modal -->
<label class="control-label">Assign Dates:</label>
<a data-target="#stack1" id="dates" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</a>            

<!-- Modal Popup Form -->
<div class="modal fade" id="stack1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Forms Due Dates</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                // The textbox 
                <input type="text" id="freq_dates" name="freq_dates" value="abcd">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['freq_dates']))
                    {
                        echo '$_POST['freq_dates']';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'No DATA';
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn default" id="cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn blue">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

```js
$("#dates").click(function(event) {
    var date = $("#start_date").val();
    var frequency = $("#frequency").val();
    var lm_id = $("#lm_id").val();

    if(date=="" || frequency=="")
    {
        bootbox.alert("Please select form Start Date and Frequency");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ URL::to('admin/geteventdates/') }}",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                frequency: frequency,
                lm_id: lm_id,
                date: date
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#freq_dates').val(data.frequency_date);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: if it is on same page and not using `post` to redirect then you should use `jquey`. If this value is coming from DB then you can directly use that in model by `$Yourvalue`

Comment: your question not clear

Comment: i wonder if the laravel docs could come in handy

Comment: i can assign the value to html tag using jQuery,  but i need to run/write the logic on the values coming from that html tag. So how can i access the html tag value on modal. @urfusion

Comment: @Gowthaman how can i access the html tag value on modal popup in variable so that i can wirte logic on it. m not able to access that html tag values on modal on same page

Comment: @lagbox thanx but i am checking it side by side laravel docs

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by open model on click event by `jquery` so you can get the value of `input`

```
<a id="dates">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</a>   
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dates").click(function () {
            $(".modal-body").html($("#freq_dates").val());
            $('.modal ').modal('show');
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: $(".modal-body").html($("#freq_dates").val()); but how can i acess it on modal i want to store that freq_dates in php so that i can write logic on it using the freq_dates.

Comment: How are you getting `req_dates` value in input? by DB or by user?

Comment: Actully from DB using ajax jquery already i am assigning the values to the freq_dates and need to rework on that so m trying to get store in php variable

Comment: I have re-write the question please view it